# C - Using execvp with user input

Tags: c, pointers, constants, execvp

I'm currently trying to have my C program read Unix arguments from the user.  I've so far searched this site but I haven't been able to figure out exactly what I'm doing wrong - though admittedly my pointer implementation skills are rather limited.

The following is how I have the code now; I've been messing around with the pointers with no luck.  The errors are also saying that I need to use const *char, but I've seen in other examples the *char can be input by the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

main()
{
    char args[128];
    //User input
    printf("> ");
    fgets(args, 128, stdin);
    execvp(args[0], *args[0]);
}
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
smallshellfile.c: In function ‘main’:
smallshellfile.c:13:21: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
smallshellfile.c:13:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘execvp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/unistd.h:575:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
```

Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. `*args[0]` is meaningless. `args` is array. `args[0]` is char. what is `*args[0]`?
2. You have to create a NULL-terminated array of `char*`, to pass as 2nd argument.
3. `args[0]` is the first char in `args`. you should pass the whole string (just `args`), not only its first char.

Try something like:

```
char *argv[]={args,NULL};
execvp(args,argv);
```

Comment: Don't forget that the command names goes in `argv[0]` and the first argument in `argv[1]` (and a null pointer in `argv[2]`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If I read the question correctly, he doesn't want to pass any arguments (except of the program name), so the NULL should be in `argv[1]`.

Comment: The [0] was there simply because I ran out of ideas.  I got rid of them and made the changes given - the errors when I'm compiling are gone but the exec doesn't do anything when called - i.e. if I try ls, it just terminates the program.

Comment: OK; so if the user types `cat` then `cat` will be executed...but if the user types `ls /bin` then the command "`ls /bin`" is unlikely to be found, so nothing will happen and there'll be no error message, even though the `execvp()` failed.  See my alternative suggestions...a different set of cheating.

Comment: And I actually do want to pass arguments.  But I think I see where that problem is coming up.  Should I be trying to parse out the arguments?

Comment: Try to replace the`fgets` by a `scanf` - I think that your problem is there.
And yes, if you want to pass arguments, you should parse them yourself. (learn about `strtok`. It may help you)

Answer (score 0):

This might work better for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char args[128];
    char *argv[] = { "sh", "-c", args, 0 };
    printf("> ");
    if (fgets(args, 128, stdin) != 0)
    {
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to exec shell on %s", args);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It has the minimum necessary headers; it has a correctly declared `main()` - C99 requires an explicit return type; it runs the shell on the information the user types in.  The error message is correctly terminated with a newline unless the user typed more than 126 characters before hitting hitting return.  If `execvp()` or any of the `exec*()` functions returns, it failed; you don't need to test its status.

I'm cheating phenomenally by making the shell do the real work.  But you may end up wanting to split what the user typed into words, so that the command is first and there are multiple arguments.  You'd then allocated a bigger `argv` array, and parse the string, putting each separate argument into its own entry in `argv` and then using `execvp()` begins to make sense.  Note that if there is I/O redirection to be done, then it is your shell that will have to do it (unless you run the real shell to do it for you - like I did).